# Display data from SQL server to listvew

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

i'm geek in vb.net, I already make vb.net from application with ms access data base. now i need to use this application for multi user and i want to use SQL server, i use this code to show data from access data base to listview :

```
 con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source = |datadirectory|\noorapp.accdb;"
        con.Open()

Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from " & Year(Now) & " where cmonth='" & m & "' order by cdate DESC", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myrow As DataRow
        For Each myrow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(0)).ToString()
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(5))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(6))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(7))
        Next
```

any solution to how make this work for sql server also?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your connection string see [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). Also change your OleDbConnection object to SQLConnection and your OleDbDataAdapter to SQLDataAdapter

Your database must already exist in the SQL Server for this to work